# Quoting a paper written in a different style

Tags: commas, quotations

In a paper I am quoting a block of text that contains the phrase "The author however does not believe ..." The copyeditor of my paper inserted comma before and after "however" as this is the journal's style. The comma, however, do not appear in the original source.

Should they be there in the quotation?

Comment: Citation advice is off-topic here sorry.

Comment: Why? This is about the usage of comma in English. Totally on-topic for me...

Comment: Not really. It's about the conventions and requirements of quotations. Since you could ask the exact same question about French or German quotes, then it shows it isn't about English. You may like to consider [writers.se].

Comment: Totally off-topic for Writers. It is not about the actual writing at all, it is about copy-editing and journal style! Why isn't there copy-editing-with-mixed-author-styles.se ??

Comment: [Editing **is** on-topic at Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)!

Comment: Admit it, you don't know the answer to my question! That's why you are policing me.

Comment: OK, I'm going to let this go now.  I can't see why the question is not on-topic according to http://english.stackexchange.com/tour It's a different question when asked about German, because punctuation rules and quoting conventions are different in different languages.

Comment: All style guides, in all languages, require quotes to be verbatim, and editorial insertions to be clearly marked (the common convention in English is to use [square brackets] and/or disclaimers like "*emphasis mine*" before or after the quoted material). Regardless of the details, however, the ethical and editorial standard is to *accurately represent the person quoted* and above all else to *avoid putting words in anyone's mouth*, and to do so consistently and in such a way that when a reader encounters quoted material, however formatted, he can trust, by default, that it's verbatim.

Comment: As you can see, Thomas, there is considerable disagreement about what questions are and are not appropriate for English Language & Usage. I take a broad view and think that your question is entirely suitable for this site, while others disagree. But either way, Dan Bron's answer in the comment above is exactly right. The copy editor should not have tried to correct the punctuation (or lack thereof) in the quotation you used.

Comment: @DanBron please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a strictly correct answer and a practical answer.

The strictly correct answer is to leave out the commas (as @DanBron explained in his comment) and add this after the quote:

> [punctuation as in original]

This follows a similar convention when your source material includes either emphasis (italic text) or misspellings.

HOWEVER, this strictly correct approach does no service for the reader, in my opinion.  Just *what* punctuation was or is out of place in the original?

---

The practical answer is to add the commas as your editor recommends.  It doesn't change the meaning of the quote at all, and thus does not harm to the source or its author.  After the quote, you could add...

> [commas added]

...to be totally honest, but what does the reader gain by this?  Nothing, in my opinion.

---

What would you do in this case?:  The source material omitted the period at the end of the first of two sentences.  If this is edited material and not from some informal source like on-line chat session, then we would conclude that omission of the period was a typographical error.  We would do our own readers a service by adding the period back in.